# How to create Amplify React app from AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, aws-amplify

I have problem that I want to create AWS Amplify React app in our CI pipeline. How do I create Amplify app from AWS CLI? Files should come from S3. Git is not an option in this case.

aws --profile master amplify create-app --name appName

This command creates amplify app, but how do i get it to use S3 files, zipped or not.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/use-an-existing-s3-bucket-for-your-amplify-project/) or [create-deployment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/amplify/create-deployment.html)

Comment: @amitd create-deployment could be solution but how do I use it to get files from S3 bucket? The documentation is so narrow...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute following aws-cli commands; There can be different combinations of commands as well.

Step 1: To create app with name as appName. `aws amplify create-app --name appName --region eu-west-1`

Step 2: To create branch. `aws amplify create-branch --region eu-west-1 --app-id "{appId from Step 1 here}" --branch-name "master"`. There are other ways to create branch as well.

Step 3: To deploy. `aws amplify start-deployment --region eu-west-1 --app-id "{appId from Step 1 here}" --branch-name "master" --source-url "s3://{s3-bucket-name}/app_src_package.zip"`

Step 4: To verify deployment status, `aws amplify get-job --region eu-west-1 --app-id "{appId from Step 1 here}" --branch-name "master" --job-id "{jobId from Step 3 here}"`

*Note: Make sure your IAM user/role has required amplify & s3 policies.*

Comment: Thanks! Will try this on monday!

Comment: I really struggled with the IAM policies for the start-deployment command here when using s3 which needs access to the bucket and objects on the bucket where the zip is located + acl access, so the actions are: ["s3:PutObject", "s3:GetObjectAcl", "s3:GetObject", "s3:ListBucket","s3:PutObjectAcl"], and ofc [amplify:StartDeployment]